# Como se diz "el colmo" em Português?

Tags: estrangeirismos, expressões-idiomáticas

**PORTUGUÊS (English follows)**

O verbo "*colmar*" quer dizer "encher".

Uma frase como "*la gota que colma el vaso*" é traduzida literalmente como "a gota que preencha o copo", embora a tradução correta seria "a palha que quebra o camelo".

Mas em espanhol, algo é "*el colmo*" quando se atinge o limite, o que não pode ser ultrapassado.

São comuns piadas sobre "*el colmo de*", e eu encontrei algumas piadas em Português sobre "*el colmo*", mas não sei se são uma adaptação ou se isso é uma coisa comum.

Exemplo:

*¿Cuál es el colmo de un ciego?* Qual é o *colmo* de um cego?
*Que le dé miedo la oscuridad.* Ter medo da escuridão.

Relacionada:
[Como posso dizer "colmo" corretamente em Inglês?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/539/how-can-i-say-colmo-properly-in-english) (em inglês, em spanish.stackexchange)

---

**ENGLISH - How do we say "*el colmo*" in Portuguese**

The verb "*colmar*" means "to fill up to the limit".

A phrase like "*la gota que colma el vaso*" is literally translated as "*a gota que preencha o copo*" (the drop that fills the cup), although the correct translation would be "*a palha que quebra o camelo*" (the straw that breaks the camel).

But in Spanish, something is "*el colmo*" when it reaches the limit, or if it can not be exceeded.

It is common to find jokes about "*el colmo*", and I found some jokes in Portuguese about "*el colmo*", but I do not know if it is an adaptation or a common thing.

Example:

*¿Cuál es el colmo de un ciego?* What is "el colmo" of a blind (person)?
*Que le dé miedo la oscuridad.* To be afraid of the dark.

Related:
[How can I say “colmo” properly in English?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/539/how-can-i-say-colmo-properly-in-english)  (in english, in spanish.stackexchange)

Comment: (Tangencial: em Portugal dizemos "a gota que faz transbordar o copo".)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em português usamos para essa expressão "o cúmulo".

*In Portuguese we use the expression "o cúmulo".*

> Qual é **o cúmulo** da cegueira?
>
> Ter medo da escuridão

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser por exemplo; colmatar, preencher.

Comment: Estas duas palavras não parecem adequar-se muito bem a todos os exemplos dados na pergunta: `a gota que *colma* o copo`, e `Qual é o *colmo* de um cego?`.